# Weight in xml - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout

I have a xml that is bellow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/Item_Rows_Height">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Items_Layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="HELLO"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_Share"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_BackGround"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_Download"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_CountVisit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_CountDownload"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Items_Layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I need to this result:

[image]

Comment: The CardView itself has an inner margin. Is that what you are trying to remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Items_Layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.4"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="HELLO"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="HELLO"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_Share"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_BackGround"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_Download"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_CountVisit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_CountDownload"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_item"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```